# Opencv: ImportError DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: opencv

The current responses are several years old, hence this post.

### `Background:`

> Windows 10 machine, nVidia GPUs (P5000), Driver 391.03, CUDA tools
>   V9.0.176, Windows OS Build 16299.309, Python version 3.6.4, installed
>   with pip (not Anaconda)

### `Task:`

> Trying to build OpenCV 3.4.1 from source, including "contrib" library.

### `Accomplished to date:`

I built `OpenCV` from source on a `Win10` machine, using `CMake`, then `Visual Studio 2015`. The "Release" build ran successfully, but the "Debug" build failed because a Python debug library couldn't be found. Set `PYTHONPATH` to `.../opencv-3.4.1/build/lib/python3/release`

### `Problem:`

When I run python and "import cv2", I get the error message in the title of this post.

### `QUESTIONS:`

1. Which DLL is python unable to find?
2. Where should it be under the `OpenCV` build directory?
3. Do I need to set `OPENCVPATH`? If so, to what?
4. What do I need to do to get the debug version of the build to run to completion (it failed at the end of a 4-hour run with a cryptic message about not being able to find a Python debug library)?

Apologies in advance for the verbose post, but any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks.

PS I would of course appreciate tips on how to fix this, but explanations of root causes (which will teach me something) are even more welcome.

Comment: how did you install the opencv python library?